# Where's my recording on a Zoom H1

Tags: zoom, h1, file

I'm a novice recorder and was using my Zoom H1 for the first time yesterday.  I can't find the first meeting I recorded with it (omg) but I can find another longer meeting.  I had pushed the record button and saw the red light, but even after plugging the thing into my computer, that first file is nowhere.  I didn't delete it - where might it be?

Answer (score 2):

Contrary to what Utopia said, you need to press the record button only once on the zoom H1. If you saw the red light (and the counter running), it was recording.

I have had a similar issue once with my H1, where after a series of recordings in recorder-unfriendly conditions (taped to the back of a car), one file became corrupt and the next one was missing.
I tried one of those drive rescue programs to see if the data was still on the memory card, but to no avail.

I'm guessing it happend because somehow the device switched off before it could write the latest recording to the card.

Comment: +1 on this comment.  Did the battery die?  If the battery goes dead before the recorder is stopped and can write to the FAT, then your data most likely went poof.  That happened to me with my H4n once.  Man, those things EAT batteries.

Answer (score 0):

Zooms work this way:

You have to press the record button twice.

When you press it once, it goes into record ready mode and flashes red.

Press it twice, and it actually records...

That might be what happened and would explain the missing file.

Comment: Thanks for writing.  Boy have I screwed up.  Glad I took notes during the meeting but now I need to hustle and make this somehow turn out.  Great learning experience for me.  

Comment: actually the H1 is a little different. 
as soon as you switch it on its monitoring and you only need to press record once.

as for the missing file, im not sure. you sure you didnt press the trash can button on the side?


Comment: Hmm - thanks for clarifying, @Jamie. I would plug the Zoom in and check inside every single folder on there. Is the second file named 02 or 01?

Comment: The instructions didn't indicate pressing the record button twice, but now that I think of it, when using my guitar interface - it tells me to "arm" it before recording.  I didn't press the trashcan icon, but I probably did press the pause button.  I'm basically f'd at this point and have to scramble to remember everything everyone said (a bunch of recording artists!)  thanks again - 
t